# How getattr() function works with variables?

Tags: python

I've been reading about getattr() function in dive into python. From that book I know it works great with modules - no questions about that! I've conducted some test and I don't know what's wrong with that snippet of code where I use getattr() with a specific variable:

```
var="lol"
a=getattr(var,"join")

a(["A","B","C"])   # output: 'AlolBlolC'

var="lll"
a(["A","B","C"])  #  output: 'AlolBlolC' - I thought It should have been 'AlllBlllC'
```

On the other hand:

```
var.join(["A","B","C"])   # output:'AlllBlllC'
```

I don't understand why after changing variable 'var' on '111' it doesn't work with reference 'a' but works in normal way with variable name.

Comment: Are you surprised that `y` equals 2 (instead of 3) after `x = 1; y = x + 1; x = 2`? If not, why does this behaviour surprise you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python, assignment to a variable doesn't change the object that variable references. It merely assigns a different object to the variable. The method held by `a` remains bound to the string `var` referenced when you called `getattr()`.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, this has nothing to do with `getattr`. Consider

```
obj = "x"
meth = obj.join
print meth("ABC") # AxBxCx

obj = "y"
print meth("ABC") # AxBxCx
```

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html says

> When an instance attribute is referenced that isn’t a data attribute, its class is searched. If the name denotes a valid class attribute that is a function object, a method object is created by packing (pointers to) the instance object and the function object just found together in an abstract object: this is the method object.

In other words, `var=obj.someMethod` creates a closure that captures `self` in a method. As already said, later assignments to the variable have no effect on this closure, because it references the object itself and not the variable.